# Weird undefined error on javascript arrow function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm joined to a react-native project and I realized something is different here like its CSS, but I think something about javascript is different too. Because I got an error on the following code:

```
const makeVal = arr =>
  arr
    .filter( i => i.checked )
    .map ( i => i.label )
    .join(', ');
```

Sometimes this function falls in the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

I cannot find it out and our leader tell me it's your fault? But I think it is backend team fault for their data passing in their API.

How I can write this function that won't fall in error?

Comment: Where is the `dot` in your code?

Comment: Assuming this is actually `arr.filter(...).map(...)` etc, then the error means that you are passing in `undefined` to the function. But you don't show us how the function is being called.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal, thank for your comment. I fix it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond, it calls be `react-native` inside `Text` component, in this function the arr is passed by `formik` object, the `field.value`. my manager told me it is not about data, its fault of your code.

Comment: Seems to me running fine in console

Comment: @ElinaSalamon - thanks, but I'm not familiar with React Native (and I suspect even if I was, this would not be enough information for me to understand what is happening). We need to see more code,  as well as the full traceback for the error. This will tell us how the function being called with the input `undefined`

Comment: @Andreas, sometime it falls in error, I don't know why.

Comment: Pretty sure it's in the data. Please provide how the input for that is generated.

Comment: @ElinaSalamon [There is nothing wrong with this code](https://jsfiddle.net/uh5sjb1q/). It's about how it is called. Without more information it's impossible for us to answer.

Comment: Give arr a default value of an empty array. const makeVal = (arr = []) => ...

Comment: I tested your code and it is working fine. From the error you get it seems that the passed value to the function is not an array. Try logging it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

You should ensure that `arr` property is actually defined and is of `array` type. It seems that in some cases `arr` passed to `makeVal` function is undefined, and therefore doesn't have `filter` method. You could try something like this:

```
const makeVal = arr => {
   if (typeof arr === 'undefined' || ! Array.isArray(arr)) {
       // "arr" is wrong, error handling
   } else {
       return  arr
           .filter( i => i.checked )
           .map ( i => i.label )
           .join(', ');
   }
}
```

Furthermore, you might want to check if `arr` elements actually contain "checked" and "label" fields, but this is a different story. OR, you could examine `makeVal` callsite and ensure that data passed to this function is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to upvote you too but because of my rep under 15 I cannot. if I reach this rep absolutely, I will upvote you. thanks.